# How do i change "Fig 1" to "Table 1"

Tags: tables, captions

So, what i want to do is to replace where it says "Fig. 1"  under this table to "Table 1 " in such a way that it will continue numbering each table after that with "Table n+1"
NOTE: This table is put in via the function "\includegraphics"

[image: Table 1]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Use the `table` environment instead of `figure`.

Comment: One of the greatest misunderstandings in LaTeX is that users think that a figure must be put inside a figure environment and a table in a `table` environment. If an image of a table is included, the result displays as table, not as figure.

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{Results \dots}
\label{tab:Results}
\end{table}
In table~\ref{tab:Results} one can find\dots
\end{document}`. If you really need to, you can replace the duck image by an image of a table. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Question i want to do the same but with equations so instead of "Fig. 1" to "Table 1 " i want it to be "equation 1" ive tried changing the environment like you suggested earlier for the table but that didnt work

Comment: For me `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\label{eq:Results}
\end{equation}
In equation~\eqref{eq:Results} one can find\dots
\end{document}` works.

Comment: @marmot i tried that just now but i didnt see "equation 1" written in the caption below it

Comment: @Zyzzx: Equations do not have a caption -- I know no math environment that allows this. You can fake it with `\begin{equation} E = mc^{2}\label{foo} \intertext{\eqref{foo}: Your description}\end{equation}`, but it would not look nice -- and you should not change the question after one feature is solved by piling up another question ...

Comment: Yes, equation labels are by default on the right, as @ChristianHupfer says. You *could* define a math environment that adds captions to equations, whether or not you will make yourself friends with that is a different question. However, if you ask a new question on how to do that, I bet you will get several answers.

Comment: If I had written LaTeX, I would have replaced both figure and table with float and used \captionof for everything.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what documentclass you are using; normally the caption in a `figure` environment is labelled as "Figure" but you say it is given as "Fig.".
Put the `\includegraphics` inside a `table` environment (but you may need to do something more if the caption starts "Tab." instead of the regular "Table", it depends on your unknown class).

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\includegraphics{<graphicsfile>}
\caption{Your caption}
\end{table}
```

If you don't get "Table" at the start of the caption then ask another question, not forgetting to provide a MWE that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including it as graphic, this table can be reproduced in tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& All & Naive & Proposed\\
& & Top-k & algorithm\\\hline
\# markers & 370 & 125 & 77\\\hline
\# clusters & -- & -- & 6\\\hline
Distance & 5 km & 5 km & 5 km\\\hline
Zoom level & 13 & 13 & 13\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{text}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to go about this is definitely to use the environments semantically, i.e. use the `table` environment for tables.

However (for the record) it is also possible to change the name in the caption of a figure: this is recorded using `figurename`, so the literal answer to the original question is:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Table}
```

Comment: Using this in a figure environment, a possible caption will appear in the `List of Figures` and not in the `List of Tables`, however...

Comment: True, but if lists of tables/figures are required, that is fixable separately.